# What determines GNU\Linux hardware requirements?

Tags: linux

I was wondering what characteristics determines GNU\Linux hardware requirements. 
Difference between for example hardware requirements for openSUSE and those for Tiny Core Linux are gigantic. Is there any other factor that affect hardware requirements, apart from desktop environment, and would it be possible to make for example openSUSE as lightweight as Tiny Core Linux? 
Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any other factor that affect hardware requirements, apart from desktop environment

Of course, some distros are far far larger than others; which would mean you need more storage. Some distro's [run entirely from RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions_that_run_from_RAM). For example for [Tin Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Gentoo_Linux_derivatives#Tin_Hat_Linux) you need 4gb RAM and for [Tiny SliTaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SliTaz) only 4MB is required.

> and would it be possible to make for example openSUSE as lightweight as Tiny Core Linux?

You can start with a large distro and remove everything unnecessary and replace as much as possible with equivalents that have lower requirements and vice versa.

Starting with a distro that contains what you want saves a lot of time tho.

Comment: +1 but there is more.  For example, a lot of the super lightweight distros are not compiled to use modern CPU architectures.  This means they can run on more CPU types, especially very old ones, like original Pentiums, 486s, and even 386s.  There are other things as well, but far too much to discuss in a comment or simple answer.